# Azure SAML User Attributes & Claims

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2b

I have an Azure AD which is configured as Identity Provider For SkillJar, and users of that Azure AD are B2B collaborated Users.

We have Configured SSO Between SkillJar and the Azure AD through the SAML (SkillJar Enterprise app in Azure)

We need to pass Users Given name and Surname to the Skilljar, to do that I have to Extract users Given name and Surname from the user.Displayname Attribute. therefore I have tried to create a SAML Attribute with a Transformation Like below but I have no idea of what should be the value for express "Space"

[Manage claim > Manage transformation][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPlOe.png

[User profile in Azure AD][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXjSA.png

Comment: Thanks @Kanishka and please follow this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization for the transformation of SAML claim. Please let us know if you need more information.

Comment: Thank you for the commenting, but still my question exist :(

can you help me to figure following out

I want to pass First name, and Surname to my application and im about to extract them from Full name ex:- ( Kanishka Samarasinha) and that names frist and second separates from a Space in between.

if I use "Extract() - After matching"  "Extract() - Before matching" transformations what should be the way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The below Transformation should work

ExtractAlpha() and Type Prefix for FirstName

[image]

ExtractAlpha() and Type Suffix for LastName

[image]

User Attributes and Claims requested By SkillJar

[image]

Because space is a special character it adds as a delimiter. If any display names have more than one space the first name and last name will not be accurate.